# 'undeclared identifier" while trying to make an instance in c++

Tags: c++, identifier

this is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Box *b = new Box(1,2,3);
}


class Box
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    Box (int aa, int bb, int cc)
    {
    a=aa;
    b=bb;
    c=cc;
    }

};
```

it doesn't compile.

(i did not split it to an h file and a cpp file)

thanks in advance

Comment: Add your full compiler error.

Comment: That said, I'd guess it's because you're trying to use the class `Box` before it's defined. Either put `main()` at the end, or add `class Box;` at the start.

Comment: As a comment to millimoose:
class Box; before main() does not work because you call the constructor of Box explicitly in main().
Forward declaration class Box; only works if you only use pointers Box*.

Comment: @millimoose Sorry, are you in a hurry? Can I ask you to consider taking a little more time/care phrasing your comments? "Can you provide the full compiler error?" or "You should include the compiler error" would be perfectly fine and contribute to a better atmosphere. Both for the askers and the answerers on this site.

Comment: @millimoose "We need you actual compiler error". "Obviously". You're not teaching the OP anything. Nor me, actually. The OP needs to understand why we can't answer it.

Comment: @sehe Perhaps your time would be better spent explaining this to the OP then, instead of finding new reasons to berate me. Seeing as you've gone from "you haven't added a 'would you kindly'" to "you're not being didactic enough". (Which is ludicrous, I think I've contributed enough in answers by now that this shouldn't be in question. Certainly not over taking a drive-by approach in pointing out a very common flaw in a single question I had no intent of paying full attention to, in the spirit of "maybe it'll save time to whoever finds it later".)

Comment: @millimoose It was you that suggested I needed better arguments. Note how I never accused you of being impolite. I wondered why you didn't phrase the comment in a way that could work so much better. Sorry if I assumed you didn't because you don't have the time. Anyways, kinda suprised at the whole personal attack that followed. I'll leave that be. (PS. The OP can read the comments too, so I _was_ explaining to the OP as well).

Comment: @sehe "Sorry, are you in a hurry?" is pretty condescending / passive-aggressive. You were and are being a bully, albeit a well-spoken one, which is what made me lash out which I admit might not have been appropriate.

Comment: @millimoose Well, again, apologies if that offended you. In fairness, my sentiment isn't even about your comment in isolation. See [here e.g.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=11989974#11989974) for what triggered my remark. Thanks for your contributions (as you can see, I know what that takes). But let's try not to forget that the small things matter as well.

Comment: @sehe Eh. I agree that that is a meme but not all SO memes are bad. I generally agree with the notion that the OP should make the job of the people answering a question as easy as they can possibly make it. This involves providing all the information they have at their disposal so as to make it easier for someone to spot the error immediately instead of having to go and fire up an IDE and run things on their own. For compile errors, the exact text of the error is a) a piece of information that is at the asker's disposal, and b) providing it does make the error easier to spot and explain.

Comment: @sehe I can understand where a default kneejerk reaction to boilerplate comment memes would come from, but this is asking for a one specific and relevant thing. It's a world of difference from, say, posting links to "What have you tried?", or Jon Skeet's question checklist, or something else that might as well be making the asker jump through hoops. I just tend to not include an explanation for the request unless the OP asks for it in order to stay on point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38130/discussion-between-sehe-and-millimoose)

Answer (score 2):

Put `main` after your `class`

```
class Box
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    Box (int aa, int bb, int cc)
    {
    a=aa;
    b=bb;
    c=cc;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Box *b = new Box(1,2,3);
}
```

The forward declaration `class Box;` at top in this case won't work, however it will work if you only use `Box* b;`

Answer (score -3):

You need to declare your class above the code that uses it.

Comment: Needs to *define* his class.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? You need to *declare* your class before you use it and you need to *define* it somewhere in the binary that can eventually be linked to. That's why headers *declare* types, but object files you can link later *define* them. Edit: There's also a reason why the error message says "*undeclared* identifier" not "undefined"; that's a link-time issue!